# How does Laravel's "withVariableName" works?

Tags: php, laravel

Looking at Laravel code I found they are passing variable from 'routes' to 'views' using the following method:

```
$arraysan = ['mike','robert','john'];    **//Variable to be passed**
return view('home')->withArraysan($arraysan); **//Variable passed with** name "withArraysan"
```

In that above syntax they call a function named `withArraysan` which doesn't exist.

Can somebody explain how its been handled in Laravel?

Answer (score 3):

For a while now, PHP has had the concept of [`magic methods`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) - these are special methods that can be added to a class to intercept method calls that do not exist.

It appears that Laravel Views implement [`__call`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) - this then intercepts a call to an undefined method on the object, and is passed both the name of the method being called as well as the arguments. In this way, the View object can then see that the `withArraysan` call began `with` and call the concrete method `with`, passing the second part `Arraysan` as the first argument, and the argument to `withArraysan` as the second part.

Answer (score 2):

If I've got your question then in Laravel they had a class `View` using magic method `__call` to handle the above function and the code for that function is like as follows

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    if (Str::startsWith($method, 'with')) {
        return $this->with(Str::snake(substr($method, 4)), $parameters[0]);
    }

    throw new BadMethodCallException("Method [$method] does not exist on view.");
}
```

And you can find this within

```
your_project_folder/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arraysan = ['mike', 'robert', 'john'];    // Variable to be passed
return view('home')->with('AnyVariable', $arraysan);
```

Try this! This will work.

Also check in home.blade.php,

```
<?php
    print_r($AnyVariable);die;
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I think you post another option used in laravel to achieve the variables passed  from "routes" to "views" but what i wondering is how they called a function named "withArraysan" which dosent exist and how they executed it without error?